# Error clipping raster using a mask layer

Tags: qgis, gdal, clip, osx

I am trying to clip a raster with a polygon with QGIS 3.0 on High Sierra OSX (I've done it before with OSX Sierra and QGIS 2.8, no issues), however I keep getting an error (see inputs in screenshot below)

[image: Input Parameters]

Here's the error:

```
*Processing algorithm…
AlgorithmDialog
Input parameters:
{ 'INPUT' : '/Users/felipearrospide/Dropbox/WATS/W04-18 Natura/2- Trabajo/gt30w100s10_dem/gt30w100s10.dem', 'MASK' : '/Users/felipearrospide/MEGA/PROYECTOS/01 2018/W04-18 Natura/2- Trabajo/Cuenca PFV Itahue.shp', 'NODATA' : 0, 'ALPHA_BAND' : False, 'CROP_TO_CUTLINE' : True, 'KEEP_RESOLUTION' : False, 'OPTIONS' : '', 'DATA_TYPE' : 5, 'OUTPUT' : '/Users/felipearrospide/MEGA/PROYECTOS/01 2018/W04-18 Natura/2- Trabajo/DEM/trial.tif' }
GDAL command:
gdalwarp -ot Float32 -of GTiff -cutline "/Users/felipearrospide/MEGA/PROYECTOS/01 2018/W04-18 Natura/2- Trabajo/Cuenca PFV Itahue.shp" -crop_to_cutline "/Users/felipearrospide/Dropbox/WATS/W04-18 Natura/2- Trabajo/gt30w100s10_dem/gt30w100s10.dem" "/Users/felipearrospide/MEGA/PROYECTOS/01 2018/W04-18 Natura/2- Trabajo/DEM/trial.tif"
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found 
Execution completed in 0.09 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': <QgsProcessingOutputLayerDefinition {'sink':/Users/felipearrospide/MEGA/PROYECTOS/01 2018/W04-18 Natura/2- Trabajo/DEM/trial.tif, 'createOptions': {'fileEncoding': 'System'}}>}*
```

Am I missing something? Should I install/reinstall/uninstall everything?
I am truly lost :(

Comment: Version 3.0 was just recently released. The release note (http://blog.qgis.org/2018/02/23/qgis-3-0-girona-is-released/) states that "we do not expect it to be as reliable as the 2.18 LTR just yet". I would uninstall and reinstall 2.18 - the current Long Term Release.

Comment: One thing (before you uninstall/reinstall) you can try is to set the same CRS to your input layer and mask layer.